# PHP - Fortnite API show me "Invalid authentication credentials"?

Tags: php, api

I would like to make a small Fortnite API, but I always get an error in the JSON file.

```
{"message":"Invalid authentication credentials"}
```

My PHP Code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
//pc, xbl, psn
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/MyName");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'TRN-Api-Key: My-API-Code'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
$fp = fopen("myStats.json", "w");
fwrite($fp, $response);
fclose($fp);

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("myStats.json"));
$solo = $data->stats->p2;//solos data
$duos = $data->stats->p10;//duos data
$squads = $data->stats->p9;//squads data

$matches = $data->recentMatches;//match data
$sesh1 = $matches[0]->id->valueInt;

$solo_wins = $solo->top1->valueInt;
$duos_wins = $duos->top1->valueInt;
$squads_wins = $squads->top1->valueInt;
$solo_matches = $solo->matches->valueInt;
$duos_matches = $duos->matches->valueInt;
$squads_matches = $squads->matches->valueInt;
$solo_kd = $solo->kd->valueDec;
$duos_kd = $duos->kd->valueDec;
$squads_kd = $squads->kd->valueDec;
$solo_games = $solo->matches->valueInt;
$duos_games = $duos->matches->valueInt;
$squads_games = $squads->matches->valueInt;
$solo_kills = $solo->kills->valueInt;
$duos_kills = $duos->kills->valueInt;
$squads_kills = $squads->kills->valueInt;

$total_matches = ($solo_matches+$duos_matches+$squads_matches);

$total_wins = ($solo_wins+$duos_wins+$squads_wins);

$total_kills = ($solo_kills+$duos_kills+$squads_kills);

$total_kd = (round($total_kills/($total_matches-$total_wins),2));

echo 'Total Matches: '.$total_matches.'<br>';
echo 'Total Wins: '.$total_wins.'<br>';
echo 'Total Kills: '.$total_kills.'<br>';
echo 'Total KD: '.$total_kd.'<br>';
echo $sesh1;

?>
```

I entered the correct API code. Why is this message written in a JSON file and not my wins? It's so crazy because it should work.

Comment: does it work if you make the same request via another tool e.g. PostMan? You can use a tool like Fiddler to examine the HTTP request generated by such a tool and by your code and check for any differences. You can also use it to check if your request's structure matches the guidance given in the Fortnite API documentation. There are two possibilities - either your credentials are invalid or your request is incorrectly structured so Fortnite can't understand. We cannot possibly advise you on the first point. On the second, you need to check the documentation against what your code is producing.

Comment: if you give us a link to the docs for the method you're trying to use, we may be able to help by checking whether what you've written is likely to result in a valid request.

Comment: @ADyson But that is against SO format, he should do that himself and then try to change it. Otherwise the question could be marked as "asking for tutorial or resource". There is no point in telling someone he can't read documentation and his implementation si wrong

Comment: @TheLaw how is that against the format?? No-one is asking for an off-site tutorial or other resource. I'm asking for information which would help people to understand and/or reproduce the issue. Without knowing the spec of the API, it's impossible to know whether the request is being written correctly or not. We need to start to narrow down the problem from the two possibilities I outlined, to a single one. I'm not _telling_ anyone the implementation is wrong, I'm asking for enough info to verify whether that's the case or not.

Comment: Hey guys, my english is realy bad but i dont have a link to Fortnite API Documentation, because it doesn't exist. I have write this code mostly alone and it should work. I have google it for hours but i don't find somthing useful. Fortnite Support don't help me at all. Said "We do not offer any support or programming support. Do not contact us for help." ... Please help me :(

Comment: Well, we don't know how it's supposed to work either, sorry, we can't read the minds of the API developers any more than you can. If you follow some of the debugging steps I outlined in my first comment you might get a clue. You need to at least narrow down whether the problem is due to your PHP code, or due to your credentials simply being incorrect or invalid (have you checked that your API Key is exactly correct and has not been banned or anything like that?). At minimum, run the same request in another tool (PostMan is quite good, for example) and see what happens.

Comment: Also here are some other code samples (mostly in other languages, but at the end of the day they just make HTTP requests) for talking to Fortnite. It appears some of them may be talking to a different API...maybe it's worth pursuing that instead, if this one won't work. https://github.com/topics/fortnite-api

Answer (score 0):

What returns on line 11? You are using `var_dump($response);`
Could you write `die();` under that line and provide us the return that it gives?

There might be something wrong on how you handle the headers. I can't check for sure right now as I am not home. But I might be able to test this out later.

Comment: Show me the same error. He stop on "die();" and show me "{"message":"Invalid authentication credentials"}". When i put "$response" in "die();", he show me 2x the same error and stops.